# x distance between two lines of points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two 1D numpy arrays A and B of size (n, ) and (m, ) respectively which correspond to the x positions of points on a line. I want to calculate the distance between every point in A to every point in B. I then need to use these distances at a set y distance, d, to work out the potential at each point in A.

I'm currently using the following:

```
V = numpy.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    xdist = A[i] - B
    r = numpy.sqrt(xdist**2 + d**2)
    dV = 1/r
    V[i] = numpy.sum(dV)
```

This works but for large data sets it can take a while so I would like to use a function similar to scipy.spatial.distance.cdist which doesn't work for 1D arrays and I don't want to add another dimension to the arrays as they become too large.

Comment: What are typical numbers for `n,m` i.e. how big are those arrays?

Comment: n ~ 10000 and m~2000

Comment: I should also add that I need to take the square root of r before I sum dV

Comment: Updated my post with a hybrid approach.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Vectorized approach**

One vectorized approach after extending `A` to `2D` with the introduction of a new axis using [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and thus making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) would be -

```
(1/(np.sqrt((A[:,None] - B)**2 + d**2))).sum(1)
```

**Hybrid approach for large arrays**

Now, for large arrays, we might have to divide the data into chunks.

Thus, with `BSZ` as the block size, we would have a hybrid approach, like so -

```
dsq = d**2   
V = np.zeros((n//BSZ,BSZ))
for i in range(n//BSZ):
    V[i] = (1/(np.sqrt((A[i*BSZ:(i+1)*BSZ,None] - B)**2 + dsq))).sum(1)
```

---

### Runtime test

Approaches -

```
def original_app(A,B,d):
    V = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        xdist = A[i] - B
        r = np.sqrt(xdist**2 + d**2)
        dV = 1/r
        V[i] = np.sum(dV)
    return V

def vectorized_app1(A,B,d):
    return (1/(np.sqrt((A[:,None] - B)**2 + d**2))).sum(1)
    
def vectorized_app2(A,B,d, BSZ = 100):
    dsq = d**2   
    V = np.zeros((n//BSZ,BSZ))
    for i in range(n//BSZ):
        V[i] = (1/(np.sqrt((A[i*BSZ:(i+1)*BSZ,None] - B)**2 + dsq))).sum(1)
    return V.ravel()
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [203]: # Setup inputs
     ...: n,m = 10000,2000
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(m)
     ...: d = 10
     ...: 

In [204]: out1 = original_app(A,B,d)
     ...: out2 = vectorized_app1(A,B,d)
     ...: out3 = vectorized_app2(A,B,d, BSZ = 100)
     ...: 
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out3)
     ...: 
True
True

In [205]: %timeit original_app(A,B,d)
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [206]: %timeit vectorized_app1(A,B,d)
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop

In [207]: %timeit vectorized_app2(A,B,d, BSZ = 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.2 ms per loop
```

We can play around with the parameter block size `BSZ` -

```
In [208]: %timeit vectorized_app2(A,B,d, BSZ = 200)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.5 ms per loop

In [209]: %timeit vectorized_app2(A,B,d, BSZ = 50)
10 loops, best of 3: 67.4 ms per loop
```

Thus, the best one seems to be giving a **`2x`** speedup with a block size of `100` at my end.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My answer turned out to be nearly identical to Divakar's after a closer look. However, you can save some memory by doing the operations in-place. Taking the sum along the second axis is more efficient than long the first.

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.randint(0,10,10) * 1.
b = numpy.random.randint(0,10,10) * 1.

xdist = a[:,None] - b
xdist **= 2
xdist += d**2
xdist **= -1
V = numpy.sum(xdist, axis=1)
```

which gives the same solution as your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use a function similar to scipy.spatial.distance.cdist which doesn't work for 1D arrays and I don't want to add another dimension to the arrays as they become too large.

[`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) works fine, you just have to reshape the arrays to have shape (n, 1) instead of (n,).  You can add another dimension to a one-dimensional array `A` without copying the underlying data by using `A[:, None]` or `A.reshape(-1, 1)`.

For example,

```
In [56]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [57]: A
Out[57]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [58]: B
Out[58]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [59]: A[:, None]
Out[59]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])

In [60]: cdist(A[:, None], B[:, None])
Out[60]: 
array([[ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  3.,  5.,  7.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  4.,  2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 7.,  5.,  3.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  6.,  4.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 9.,  7.,  5.,  3.,  1.]])
```

To compute `V` as shown in your code, you can use `cdist` with `metric='sqeuclidean'`, as follows:

```
In [72]: d = 3.

In [73]: r = np.sqrt(cdist(A[:,None], B[:,None], metric='sqeuclidean') + d**2)

In [74]: V = (1/r).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this and it works but it takes longer with my data sets. I think this is because cdist creates an n x m array which seems to be slower than overwriting the same n x 1 array m times.

Comment: I'll ask the same question Divakar asked above:  what are typical values for `m` and `n`?  The performance advantage of using `cdist` or vectorized numpy solutions typically occurs when the arrays are sufficiently large.

Comment: n ~ 10,000 and m~2000